# Integrability of $f(x)\sqrt{\frac{1}{x}}$ for $f\in\mathcal L^2$ and $\|f\|_2=1$

Tags: real-analysis, lp-spaces

Is it true that for $f\in\mathcal L^2$ and $\|f\|_2=1$, $$\int_0^\infty f(x)x^{-1/2}dx<\infty?$$ I'm fairly stuck on this...(and I really hope it is true).

In case it helps seeing a generalization, we could also ask for $f\in\mathcal L^{p^*}$ and $\|f\|_{p^*}=1$, is $$\int_0^\infty f(x)x^{-1/p}dx<\infty,$$
where $\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{p^*}=1$.

Comment: This would be more convincing if $x^{-1/p} \in L^p((0,\infty))$.

Comment: @EricTowers that would have been nice yes... maybe we can think of a counterexample?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not true. A counter-example is given by
$$
             f(x) = \left\{\begin{array}{cc}
                               0, & 0 \le x < 1, \\
                               \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}(1+\ln x)}, & 1 \le x < \infty.
                           \end{array}\right.
$$
$f \in L^2$ with $\|f\|=1$ because
\begin{align}
        \int_{0}^{\infty} f(x)^2 dx
     &= \int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x(1+\ln x)^2}dx \\
     &=\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(1+\ln x)^2}\frac{d}{dx}(1+\ln x)dx \\
     & = \left.-\frac{1}{1+\ln x}\right|_{x=1}^{\infty}=1.
\end{align}
However,
\begin{align}
     \int_{0}^{\infty}f(x)\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}dx
    &  = \int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x(1+\ln x)}dx \\
    & = \int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{1+\ln x}\frac{d}{dx}(1+\ln x)dx \\
    & = \ln(1+\ln x)|_{x=1}^{\infty}=\infty.
\end{align}